# MDX Help and tutorial

Tags: mdx

Hello guys again here with my MDX headaches (why does my boss think programmer = solve anything computer related).

The measure of the Filter 
Productos is compose this way [Casa].[Linea].[Producto] and I am trying to filter by Linea 72 and 74, outside this anyone know a good tutorial online or book for MDX?

Anyways here my MDX so far

`SELECT 'Dic  1 2010' AS Fecha, A.*

from (SELECT
"[Measures].[Piezas Dia]",
"[Measures].[P Redondeadas]"
FROM openrowset('MSOLAP'
,'DATASOURCE=XXX
;Initial Catalog=XXX
; User Id=XXX;Password=XXX;',
'WITH  SET [Lineas] AS ''
FILTER(DESCENDANTS([PRODUCTOS],[LINEA],SELF),

ANCESTOR([PRODUCTOS].CURRENTMEMBER,SELF) <> [74 VARIOS] AND

ANCESTOR([PRODUCTOS].CURRENTMEMBER,SELF) <> [72 VARIOS] )''
Member [Measures].[Piezas Dia]   AS ''sum([Lineas],[Measures].[|P| Venta Dia Año Actual])''

Member [Measures].[P Redondeadas] AS ''sum([Lineas],[Measures].[Venta Piezas Redondeadas])''
SELECT {[Measures].[Piezas Dia], [Measures].[P Redondeadas]} on columns 
FROM [Venta Gerencial]
WHERE ([Fecha Diario].[Fecha].&[2010].&[12].&[1])')) as A`

Thanks for all help provided.

Comment: Can you set your query as code please. I want to help you but this way I won't even read your query. Thank you.

Comment: My boss thinks programmer = fix anything with a plug on it

Comment: My friends think the same thing.  They will ask me any computer question, like they've never heard of Google.  Apparently, I'm an "expert" with Excel and Access, even though I haven't used either in the last few years.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find an 'gentle' introduction to MDX [here](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx_tutorial/gentle_introduction.html)

Answer (score 4):

You asked for a book referral.  My boss just purchased SQL Server 2008 MDX Step by Step for me.  I'm beginning to go through it and I like the way it is laid out.  I've been programming in T-SQL for over ten years and MDX is just close enough to confuse me.  This book is helping me think different about my code and coding practices.  I haven't finished it, but I do think that it might be a good one for you to start with, as you can jump in anywhere in the book to learn what you need to know.

Comment: I have almost finished "Step by Step" but like you @DataGirl i have been working with T-SQL before and it takes some time to grasp the "cube thing".. great book though!

Answer (score 1):

Should it really be a , instead of a ; ***here***:

`FROM openrowset('MSOLAP' ***,*** 'DATASOURCE=HDZNT10`